# MySQL Error in SQL Syntax. MySQL Workbench and WindowsForm Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, mysql-workbench

В базе данных создана таблица (13 столбцов). Она подключена к DataGridView.
В таблицу должна добавляться строка с данными нажатием кнопки. Кнопка активирует процедуру добавления данных в базу данных.
Ошибка: syntax to use near ''2021-06-08', '1', '1', '2154437', '355', '1', '1', '1', '3.570', '420/370', ' '' at line 1"
Ошибка возникает при нажатии кнопки "Добавить" в БД.
Код процедуры:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `ins_hall`(Date_hall varchar(45), Duty_hallmark int, Number int, Melt_number int, Metal_grade varchar(45), Ingot_number int, Syphon int, Received int, Weight varchar(45), Profile varchar(45), Chemical_analysis varchar(45), Notation varchar(255))  
BEGIN  
insert into hallmark (Date_hall, Duty_hallmark, Number, Melt_number, Metal_grade, Ingot_number, Syphon, Received, Weight, Profile, Chemical_analysis, Notation)  
value (Date_hall, Duty_hallmark, Number, Melt_number, Metal_grade, Ingot_number, Syphon, Received, Weight, Profile, Chemical_analysis, Notation);  
END
```

Место в форме в котором выдает ошибку:

```
public void ins_hall(string Date_hall, int Duty_hallmark, int Number, int Melt_number,
            string Metal_grade, int Ingot_number, int Syphon, int Received, string Weight,
            string Profile, string Chemical_analysis, string Notation)
        {
            BD BDclass = new BD();
            BDclass.executeQuery($"Execute ins_hall '{Date_hall}', '{Duty_hallmark}', '{Number}', '{Melt_number}'," +
                $"'{Metal_grade}', '{Ingot_number}', '{Syphon}', '{Received}', '{Weight.Trim()}'," +
                $"'{Profile}', '{Chemical_analysis}', '{Notation}'");
        }
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как исправить это?

Comment: `values` должно быть в запросе, а не `value`

Comment: Вставил values, добавил Execute перед ins_hall  Ошибка изменилась на: syntax to use near ''2021-06-08', '1', '1', '2154437', '355', '1', '1', '1', '3.570', '420/370', ' '' at line 1"

Comment: Тогда  обновите текст вопроса